# What java library for graph algorithms demonstration?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I would like to ask if you know any library that can be useful in demonstrating how does graph algorithms work? My job is to make an app that will show step-by-step how does certain graph algoritms work. I started with JUNG however there are serious problems durring animating the steps of the algorithm. On evey step I would like to show which node or edge is being analized. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) is an open source library for drawing graphs (the ones made from nodes and edges). sounds like what youre looking for.
[image]

Comment: I guess jgraph is a charting/diagramming lib, OP is asking about Graph theory visualisation.

Comment: graph draws graphs, in the mathematical/comp-sci meaning, which is what i understand the OP is asking for.

Comment: interesting! does it also come with a scripting language, to write graph algos?

Comment: @vikasing - not that i know of. it just lays out and draws graphs.

Comment: The doc talks about a java api, need to check out .. http://jgraph.github.com/mxgraph/docs/manual_javavis.html

Comment: @radai: the screenshot comes from your app? is the source available somewhere?

Comment: @NotJustANumber - no, its not mine.

Comment: @radai: do you know where I can find the source of this app?

Comment: @NotJustANumber - yeah sure. the image is taken from here - http://www.lucabonaldo.it/jgraph/, and there's source attached (zip at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki) and how to use it with JAVA: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java